# Media player create second parameter showing error

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-xml

I am devloping a media player that plays single song saved inside project folder called album and name of song his song.

```
    songName.setText("song.mp3");
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.album.song);
```

But im getting error as album cannot be resolved,please suggest me the solution.

Comment: Your song name should start with Capital Letter, If this not solves your problem then try restarting your IDE. or enable `Build Automatically`

Comment: You can't use the "album" folder. You need a "raw folder". Check out my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the folder `album`. Create a folder called `raw` in the `res` folder. You should end up having this

```
res/raw/song.mp3
```

Then modify your code as follows:

```
songName.setText("song.mp3");
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.song);
```